# Recursive SQL consult PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, tree, recursive-query

I'm trying to do a recursive sql query, searching for all the children of a father and the children of that children, and so on.. The problem with the code below is that it only retrieves the first children tree.

- I need to save all the emails of the entire tree in an array

  ```
  $hermanos = array();
  function obtener($id){
      $res = mysql_query("SELECT email,id FROM usuarios WHERE padre = '$id'", Conectar::con());
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
          if ($row['email'] != 'waiting') {
              $hermanos[] = $row['email'];
              obtener($row['id']);
          }
      }
      return $hermanos;
  }
  $a = obtener($invitado);
  print_r($a);
  ```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

From the vague description I think you want another solution. This is called Hierchial data retireval according to db language. I think these kind of recursive queries should be done on db end with procedures/views
You can check these links for heirchial data

1. [Sol1 with sql view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199942/getting-hierarchy-data-from-self-referencing-tables)
2. [Article about Hierarchical data in
   mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
3. [another soln with view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624755/recursive-query-on-a-self-referential-table-not-hierarchical)